# How to solve end Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt while installing Ubuntu20 in VMware Workstation12 pro?

Tags: kernel, vmware

Here's a screenshot to show the error prompted at the time of installation of Ubuntu20.4 in VMware workstation 12 Pro

[image]

Comment: This question should provide more details.  Please read our help topic on [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) You can return to [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1294303/edit) your question to add details.